# git rebase local pull request has push error

Tags: git, request, bitbucket, pull

I want to a cleanup before doing a pull request. I want my commits to be combined to one. This is where im stuck:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

with this comment:

```
pick 73b9823709a serious work
squash ce0afac6b89 test2
squash da4492e95f2 test3
```

log says then:

```
enter code here`commit 50afb6b80d0315f38df5992429c2221a5bd05478 (HEAD -> feature/feature1)
Author: me
Date:   Fri Dec 2 10:50:01 2023 +0800
    serious work
 
   test2

    test3
```

When I do the push to the server I get

```
$ git push    
To ssh://server    
! [rejected]                feature/feature1 -> feature/feature1 (non-fast-forward)    
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://server'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What do I need to to thta the server eats it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: Rewritten history (rebase rewrite history so it diverges from remote) requires force-pushing: `git push --force origin feature/feature1`

Comment: ok ill give it a try

Comment: it says it is not allowed because it is not configured